# Using WP_Query and Query_post for the loop?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, loop, query-posts, exclude

I am using the code below to call post from a certain Taxonomy term. My intentions are to mix that into the normal loop.

I'm am not trying to create two different loops, but one loop that displays the post from the taxonomy term as well as the original post in the loop, all together.

The problem is that the code below made the original loop disappear, what should i do. I am not great at writing code, I am learning. Can someone please help me.

```
<?php // Create empty array to store post ids in
     $excludes = array();

                     $args=array(
                     'post_type' => array ('gallery','videos'),
         'taxonomy'=>'series',
         'term' => 'pretty-little-liars',
                     'post_status' => 'publish',
                    );
                    query_posts( $args );

if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) will clobber the main query. You've overwritten the original set of posts. **Don't use `query_posts`** Instead create a new [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object for your second set of posts, and another Loop.

It sounds like what you are trying to do is overly complicated. "Mixing" two queries is not likely to be worth the effort. It appears that you are going to have two queries anyway, so just run two Loops.

Your first Loop would look like you have it already.

```
if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
  // 
endwhile; endif;
```

Your second, using a new `WP_Query` object, would look like:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
  // 
endwhile; endif;
```

If you really must "mix" the two Loops then:

```
$combloop = $posts;
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$combloop = $combloop + $my_query->posts;
foreach ($combloop as $post) {
  setup_postdata($post);
  //
}
```

Loops really aren't meant to be merged like that. I believe it should work but you could have problems, especially with something like pagination.

Comment: I changed the last two lines of the code to what you have posted but now all of my post are missing.

Comment: You also need the normal Loop -- `if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();`

Comment: Where do i add that, and how, sorry if I ask of too much I haven't learned this part of php yet.